# PHP Class Method when to return or not to return

Tags: php, class, methods

Within the class, I created a set method if what that is called that accepts data.

```
    <?php
    public function set_name($name)
    {
    $this->name = ucwords(trim($name));
    // return $this->name;
    }
    ?>
```

My question is, do I have to return the result of the function or not necessary. If not why? I know in the display() method you have to return like so: return $this->name;. I'm really confused.

Comment: Whether or not to return from a method is dependent on what your application needs, if (for example) you want a fluent interface, you would return `$this`... but there is no right or wrong answer. If you don't provide a return statement, PHP will actually return a null value

Comment: Please provide some code and clarify your question

Comment: show what you have done? your code

Comment: There I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to return anything.

However, it's good practice to return something on certain functions to perform tests on it, even if it's just true or false, to clarify that the function performed correctly.

Given your code, generally, I personally don't set a return on setters. So it's fine not to return anything.

For example, you may want to test that your name only contains letters and return false if it doesn't

```
<?php
public function set_name($name) {
    if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z]+/", $name) {
        $this->name = ucwords(trim($name));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

Then you'd call it by:

```
<?php
        if(!set_name($name)) {
            echo "There was an error";
        }
?>
```

However, this doesn't comply with mvc framework.

Comment: Throwing exceptions would be a perfectly valid alternative for whether the function performed correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

In Object Oriented programming language return the value is the best. Otherwise it will be childish and hard to maintain bugs when your sites grow bigger and it tend to errors prone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't HAVE TO return the result in a setter function, the best use is to make some getter functions to get the datas.

Otherwise my point of view with setter is to return $this. With this little trick you can chain up setter functions.

For exemple :

```
class C
{
    private $arg;
    private $arg2;

    function setArg($NewArg)
    {
        // your tests or so
        $this->arg = $NewArg;
        return $this;
    }

    function setArg2($NewArg)
    {
        // your tests or so
        $this->arg2 = $NewArg;
        return $this;
    }

    function getArg()
    {
        return $this->arg;
    }

    function getArg2()
    {
        return $this->arg2;
    }
}
```

And you can use it that way :

```
$Item = new C();
$Item->setArg('hello')
     ->setArg2('hi');

$Item->getArg(); // return 'hello'
$Item->getArg2(); // return 'hi'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more semantic in this case. Do I expect a function called `set_name` to give me the name? No, not really, that sounds silly. In this case, I wouldn't return anything.

Because a function should only do one thing, you should always be able to reduce the choice to a binary "yes, I'd expect it to return something" or "no, that doesn't make any sense" decision.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking your methods should do what somebody would **expect them to do just by looking at their names** (some people will hate me for saying this).

It's always a good idea to put yourself in the position of a programmer who has to work with your code. If had to use a method called: `set_name()` he would never expect it to return something.

*Your methods always should do what one would expect them to do and complain to the outer environment through exceptions. Not more, not less.*

If you put this into practice: Congratulations. You have just built yourself a great and reliable alarm bell for **methods that are doing too much** ([seperation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)) and you're a step closer to clean software design.

Of course that's not something you would force come hell or high water (nothing is), but that's something you need to decide by yourself. If you cannot do that for whatever reasons (for example *method chaining*, which has been mentioned several times) , you could provide a good documentation of your class(es) and make clear what the methods actually do.